# Datetime picker in boostrap and angularjs 1

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datepicker

Please any idea about datetime picker in boostrap 3 and angularjs 1.
I am looking for one and i didn't find it.
I want that the user can pick the date first then the time.
Best Regards

Comment: You can try [angular ui bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepicker)

Comment: @Pete Thank you for answering this issue. I already saw this link. I am looking for datetime picker these ones contains just date and time as default. I want that user  select the time too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for people who have the same issue, I have used angular-moment-picker and it solves my problem.
this link is useful:
[Angular-moment-picker](https://github.com/indrimuska/angular-moment-picker)